# shiny UI - How to make the text start at the same place after the dot sign

Tags: r, shiny

My original code:

`fluidRow(
    h4("• xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.")`

Which will looks like

• xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxx

As describe, I have a dot sign symbol like "•" and have multiple rows of the description behind it. Could someone instruct me how to make the description behind the dot sign start at the same place like how it represent in the "Microsoft Word" application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want your `h4` headings to look like [bulleted lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456613/8099834). You also want long text to be [indented the same amount as the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17514460/8099834). We can achieve this by adding CSS.

Try this out:

```
library(shiny)
css <- HTML(
        "h4{
                display: list-item;
                list-style-type: disc;
                list-style-position: inside;
                text-indent: -1em;
                padding-left: 1em;}"
        )
ui <- fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(css)),
        fluidPage(
                h1("Bullet h4 Headings"),
                h4("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                   sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
                   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
                   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
                   nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                   sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]